# Exporting index from Solr to a file, with fields illegal for FieldCache

Tags: apache, solr, solr-schema

I'm trying to export Solr index to a JSON file. However, among the 2 fields I care about, one of them (field `A`) is `multivalued`, another (field `B`) `neither indexed nor has doc values` (this field is probably missing schema). Both cause error that says `can not use FieldCache on a field which is ...`

The schemas of these fields is on remote server, and shouldn't be changed. Is it possible then to export the index with these fields anyway? Thank you!

p.s. If possible I would also like to `fl` on these 2 fields since they are all I need.

Comment: `#` has special meaning in URLs. Are you sure anything after that value is being included?  And why doesn't your query seem correct? What is included that shouldn't be (or the opposite)?

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for pointing that out. Also I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you probably want to write an export script yourself, [using a cursor mark](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/pagination-of-results.html) to speed up retrieval (to use the /export feature, the fields *has* to have docValues enabled).

There's examples in a few languages for fetching all docs on the cursor mark page, and they can be applied almost directly (you'll have to add the JSON writing yourself) to your result set.

> ```
> SolrQuery q = (new SolrQuery(some_query)).setRows(r).setSort(SortClause.asc("id"));
> String cursorMark = CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_START;
> boolean done = false;
> while (! done) {
>   q.set(CursorMarkParams.CURSOR_MARK_PARAM, cursorMark);
>   QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(q);
>   String nextCursorMark = rsp.getNextCursorMark();
>   doCustomProcessingOfResults(rsp);
>   if (cursorMark.equals(nextCursorMark)) {
>     done = true;
>   }
>   cursorMark = nextCursorMark;
> }
> ```

Make sure to use a rather large `r` value so the number of round trips is reduced.

Comment: Thanks. My results don't need to be sorted. Could this be faster/easier given that?

Comment: No, a cursorMark requires the result set to be sorted, since it otherwise wouldn't know where to start in the result set.